# Compile error when trying to debug a Visual Studio integration project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-sdk

I'm currently working on a Visual Studio integration project for VS2010 (a custom highlighter) I'm using Irony and the LanguageServiceTemplate from this [Code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/VSLanguageService.aspx). However that template is build for 2008 and the changes made in VS2010 when it comes to integrating breaks the template.

When I try to compile I get the following error:

> Source.extension.vsixmanifest file not found in project. If a file with this name is present in the project, make sure the build action is set to "None".

Any ides of what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options depending on how your package is constructed.

1) Edit the project file and remove the following line.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets" />
```

If you do this, you will lose a few things like the automatic zipping of your item and project templates.

2) Add a source.extension.vsixmanifest file to the root of your project. You can get one by creating a new VSIX Project. After you install the Visual Studio 2010 SDK, this is under the Extensibility category. If you add no content, it won't create a vsix file.

The second method is probably the best route to go. I have a specific VSIX project that I use to pull in various other package projects. If you only have one project, you can use the new vsixmanifest file to include the project to make an installer.